# LARAVEL 9: How to export data to excel based on filter data (id, month and years) using maatwebsite

Tags: excel, laravel, export-to-excel, maatwebsite-excel, data-filtering

I'm making an export data to excel based on employee_id filter, month and year of absence:
[image: filter data].

when the filter is submitted the data appears in the table below:
[image: data]

I have managed to get the data, but when the Download Excel button is clicked, the contents are just empty Excel, like this:
[image: excel]

the data does not enter the excel.

My Controller:

```
 public function rekapabsensiExcel(Request $request)
{
    $idkaryawan = $request->id_karyawan;
    $bulan      = $request->query('bulan',Carbon::now()->format('m'));
    $tahun      = $request->query('tahun',Carbon::now()->format('Y'));

    // simpan session
    $idkaryawan = $request->session()->get('idkaryawan');
    $bulan      = $request->session()->get('bulan');
    $tahun      = $request->session()->get('tahun',);

    // dd($idkaryawan,$bulan,$tahun );

    if(isset($idkaryawan) && isset($bulan) && isset($tahun))
    {
        $data = Absensi::where('id_karyawan', $idkaryawan)
        ->whereMonth('tanggal', $bulan)
        ->whereYear('tanggal',$tahun)
        ->get();
        // dd($data);
    }else{
        $data = Absensi::all();
    }
    return Excel::download(new RekapabsensiExport(['data'=>$data, 'idkaryawan'=>$idkaryawan]),'rekap_absensi_bulanan.xlsx');
}
```

My RekapAbsensiExport.php:

```
<?php

 namespace App\Exports;

 use App\Models\Absensi;
 use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

class RekapabsensiExport implements FromCollection
{
protected $id_karyawan;

// function __construct($id_karyawan) {
//     $this->id_karyawan = $id_karyawan;
// }
 public function headings(): array {
    return [
        "No. ID","ID Karyawan","NIK","Tanggal","Jam Kerja","Jam Masuk","Jam Pulang",
        "Scan Masuk","Scan Pulang","Normal","Riil","Terlambat","Plg Cepat","Absent",
        "Lembur","Jml Jam Kerja","pengecualian","Harus C/I","Harus C/O","Departemen",
        "Hari Normal","Akhir Pekan","Hari Libur","Jml Kehadiran","Lembur Hari Normal",
        "Lembur Akhir Pekan","Lembur Hari Libur"
    ];
}
/**
* @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
*/
public function collection()
{
    return Absensi::where('id_karyawan',$this->id_karyawan)->get();
}
}
```

What part did I go wrong? Please help

Comment: You are currently passing an array of values to the Export class. But your commented-out constructor function is only configured to accept a single parameter.

Comment: Do you have sample code for a problem like this?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you get no response to this statement because `$this->id_karyawan` is `null` as you have not properly passed the value through.

```php
return Absensi::where('id_karyawan', $this->id_karyawan)->get();
```

Above, you are passing an array of values to the Export class. But your commented-out constructor function is only configured to accept a single parameter. If we stick to single parameters, you could do something like this.

```php
return Excel::download(new RekapabsensiExport($data, $idkaryawan),'rekap_absensi_bulanan.xlsx');
```

Then your export constructor would look like this.

```php
protected $data;
protected $id_karyawan;

function __construct($data, $id_karyawan) {
    $this->data = $data;
    $this->id_karyawan = $id_karyawan;
}
```

Comment: I get error like this :Too few arguments to function App\Exports\RekapabsensiExport::__construct(), 1 passed in C:\laragon\www\hrms\app\Http\Controllers\admin\AbsensiController.php on line 244 and exactly 2 expected